# httpClient: How to check whether the connection was already closed by the server side

Tags: java, apache, sockets, httpclient

We connect to a data provider and keep reading XML data in an endless loop using HttpClient. We already set connection timeout and socket timeout in the Java code. However, when the connection is closed on the HTTP server side, our application does not throw any exception and just hangs there doing nothing. Because of this behavior, when the server is up the Java code will not reconnect. Is there any way to see whether the socket connection was already closed by the server side?

In addition, https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html mentioned how to close STALE connections, but it still does not solve our problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Code snippet:

```
private static final HttpClientConnectionManager CONN_MGR = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();

public boolean connectToServer() {
    disconnect();

    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000)
            .setSocketTimeout(15 * 1000).build();

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .setConnectionManager(CONN_MGR)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        connected = true;

        return true;
    } catch (Exception re) {
        LOGGER.error("error", re);
    }

    return false;
}

public void process() {
    String xml = null;
    while (!shuttingDown) {
        try {

            /* if we know the server side closed the connection already here
               we can simply return and scheduler will take care of anything else. */

            xml = reader.readLine();
            lastSeen = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(xml)) {
                continue;
            }
            xml = xml.trim();

            // processing XML here
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ie) {
            /* We see SocketTimeoutException relatively often and
             * sometimes NullPointerException in reader.readLine(). */
            if (!shuttingDown) {
                if(!connectToServer()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            LOGGER.error("other RuntimeException", re);
            break;
        }
    }

    // the scheduler will start another processing.
    disconnect();
}

// called by the scheduler periodically
public boolean isConnected() {
    CONN_MGR.closeExpiredConnections();
    CONN_MGR.closeIdleConnections(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now - lastSeen > 15000L) {
        LOGGER.info("call disconnect() from isConnected().");
        disconnect();
    }

    return connected;
}
```

Comment: Maybe by catching the *IOException*?

Comment: In process() method when IOException or NullPointerException is caught we disconnect and then reconnect.

Comment: I created a simple HTTP server and used the same code as the code to see if CONN_MGR.closeExpiredConnections() helps or not. After minutes I shut down the HTTP server my code still hangs at xml = reader.readLine() without any error or Exception. Please note each time CONN_MGR.closeExpiredConnections() is called I print out a message in the log file and I really saw the messages there. In a word, CONN_MGR.closeExpiredConnections() is called periodically in my code, but it does not end up with an Exception so my code will not reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I think with the introduction of Automatic Resource management in java 1.7

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

cleaning up of stale connections has been taken care and even on the worst case it has been taken care by the implementation providers carefully by monitoring the connection

Apache HttpClient uses HttpClientConnectionManager and other utility classes that does the job of cleaning the stale connections.

Comment: Thank you very much, Barath! Originally I said that closing the stale connections does not help. Most likely I am wrong because normally process() does not return and it is called by a Spring scheduler. Because of that reason, CONN_MGR.closeExpiredConnections() is not called periodically. I will let you know whether CONN_MGR.closeExpiredConnections() helps or not.

Comment: Hi @Barath! CONN_MGR.closeExpiredConnections() does not help for my case. For details please see the comment in my post.

Answer (score 0):

After the last catch block add a finally block for your cleanup code.

> finally {
>             CONN_MGR.shutdown();
>       }

As per documentation it shuts down connection manager and releases allocated resources

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ashish!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you have other issues

Answer (score 0):

We avoided the problem by closing the connection from another thread when no data coming in for more than 15 seconds. More specifically now isConnected() method is as follows:

```
// called by the scheduler periodically
public boolean isConnected() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now - lastSeen > 15000L) {
        disconnect();
    }

    return connected;
}
```

Of course, the reading part get will **java.net.SocketException: Socket closed** or **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is still allocated** when this happens.

After this change everything works fine.